# how to get values from a large object

Tags: typescript

i have an object with more than 600 entries. shown below is a sample of it.
i would like to know the fastest way to iterate through that object and obtains all values related to the key `eppo' and save these values in another array

Also I would like to know also how to prevent duplicates please?i mean if the there are several entried with key eppo and have the same value, then only one of them is added to the list.
**object**:

```
[
{
    "pppId": "024675-00",
    "eppo": "PAVSA"
},
{
    "pppId": "024675-00",
    "eppo": "ALLCE"
},
{
    "pppId": "024675-00",
    "eppo": "BRSOC"
},
{
    "pppId": "024675-00",
    "eppo": "APUGD"
},
{
    "pppId": "024675-00",
    "eppo": "PRNPN"
},
{
    "pppId": "024675-00",
    "eppo": "PYUCO"
},
```

]

Comment: `Array.map(x => x.eppo)`. This returns all the values for `eppo` in array. Is this what you want?

Comment: @YongShun yes. thanks. but i would like to know also how to prevent duplicates please?i mean if the there are several entried with key eppo and have the same value, then only one of them is added to the list..is that achievable please

Comment: In addition to @YongShun: use a `Set` to get unique values: `const result = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.eppo))];`

Comment: What do you mean by ‘related to the key `eppo'’?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?retiredLocale=de) to obtain the values and pass them to a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set?retiredLocale=de) to prevent duplicates:

```
const result = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.eppo))];
```